# How call a function when my array is filled

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a function that build a chart with chart.js, but sometimes the function runs when the previous function where I get the data isn't done yet, so the chart breaks, how do I call my function just when I have all the data I need??
I want to use something different then setTimeout, because I already use it and sometimes it fails anyway, I don`t want to just keep increasing the timeout number

```
    if (regionData !== undefined) {
    that.hasData = true;
    Object.entries(regionData).forEach(e => {
      let obj = {};
      let value = 0;
      let regionD = all_regions.map(function (e) { return e.id; }).indexOf(e[0]);
      obj["regionDescription"] = all_regions[regionD].data.d;
      obj["region"] = e[0];
      if (e[1] !== undefined && e[1]["month"] !== undefined) {
        value = e[1]["month"][e[1]["month"].length - 1];
      }
      obj["regio"] = value;
      regionS.push(obj);
    });
    that.buildChart(regionS, lastMonth);
  }
```

That's where I call my chart function

Comment: if the `regionS`'s length is same at the end as of the regionData then you can check for the length.. and then execute the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the rest of your code but based on your description there is one simple logical solution.

The problem is that the buildChart function runs before the getChartData function.
Solution. Call the buildChart function after getChartData function.
Pseudo code example,

```
const getChartData = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        Run your HTTP request and retrieve your data
        resolve(chart data ready to be used)
    });
}
const buildChart = () => {
    // do your chart building here
}
//then you run the functions in sequence.
getChartData().then(buildChart);
```

Comment: It's something like that, sometimes the chart works, and sometimes don't.

Comment: If you use promises( like i showed above ) then you won't have that problem. Your first function will get the data and pass it on to the next one that will build the chart.